# How can you upload contacts to the DocuSign address book?

Tags: docusignapi

Is there an import tool for this?

Answer (score 1):

There currently isn't a way to do this directly in the DocuSign web app, but there is a SOAP API available for this.  Linked here is an Excel file with VBA to load a list of contacts from the spreadsheet into a DocuSign account as a proof of concept.

This *could* be certified and used to import contacts to an address book.

[Excel VBA Contact Upload Example](https://docusigninc.box.com/s/sk60w30ulpeiiw7yl2flgyfrzs3u1r3m)